# How do I close the browser window at the end of a Selenium test?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver, browsers

I have googled for the answer, but the `.stop()` so frequently mentioned doesn't work for me. The Chrome window the test was running in remains open.

```
def test_getResults(self):
    sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/')
    sel.start()
    # do stuff

def tearDown(self):
    sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/')
    sel.close()
    sel.stop()
```

Any ideas? I'm using Selenium Server 2.8.0 with Python 2.6 and mostly using Chrome 14 windows to test.

Comment: Is there a quit method?

Comment: Yes there is - browser.quit();  Although when I used to run these types of tests before switching to WebDriver I used to have in my TearDown - self.selenium.stop()  That usually did it for me.

Comment: Okay. I will try .quit(). I found that .stop() will stop the server, but not close the window.

Comment: .quit() did not work

Comment: I verified in C# that webdriver.Quit() closes a firefox window, I didn't try it with a chrome driver.

Comment: I saw there was an old defect on Selenium not closing Chrome that was fixed a few months ago, maybe you should reopen it?

Comment: That may be what I'm encountering. I will test with another browser when I get a chance.

Comment: I tried with Firefox. .stop() doesn't work. .close() results in "Exception: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?"

Comment: You need to use "quit()". I don't think "close()" would actually close the last remaining window.

Answer (score 45):

`driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` are two different methods for closing the browser session in Selenium WebDriver.

`driver.close()` - It closes the the browser window on which the focus is set.

`driver.quit()` – It basically calls driver.dispose method which in turn closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session gracefully.

You should use `driver.quit()` whenever you want to end the program. It will close all opened browser window and terminates the WebDriver session. If you do not use `driver.quit()` at the end of program, WebDriver session will not close properly and files would not be cleared off memory. This may result in memory leak errors.

Comment: Hi Sneha Singh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is a good start, but you could make it better by adding a bit more context; can you describe the difference between the driver.close and driver.quit methods and how you would choose between them? Maybe including links to official documentation would help too - see the advice at [answer].

Comment: Does the context manager `with webdriver.Firefox() as wd` take care of `quit` for you?

Comment: This is a very old question, but maybe my expirience will help someone. I wanted to close a browser page but do not close the browser itself. `driver.close()` did not worked as expected, so I just did `driver.get('about:blank')` instead.

Answer (score 21):

You're actually creating a second Selenium session in your tearDown() function. You need to put the session created in setUp() into an instance variable, then close that session in tearDown().

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/')
        self.selenium.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()

    def test_bar(self):
        self.selenium.open("/somepage")
        #and so forth
```

Answer (score 10):

I have worked with Web Driver in both java and C# and I use

In Java :

```
WebDriver driver;      
driver.quit();
```

In C#  :

```
IWebDriver Driver;
Driver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, using selenium webdriver for Chrome, I needed to call `stop_client()` before `close()`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

in setUp():

```
options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") # optional and off-topic, but it conveniently prevents the popup 'Disable developer mode extensions' 
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

In tearDown():

```
self.driver.stop_client()
self.driver.close()
```

Comment: May we just call driver.quit() for that?

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver;      
driver.quit();
```

Above will close all open browser windwos.

And

```
WebDriver driver;      
driver.close();
```

This will close current browser window in focus.

Answer (score 1):

Using TestNG and Java.
Assume this method is located in some BaseTest class which is inherited by test class, so try this:

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
protected void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
}
```

Comment: why the last command? driver=null;

Comment: I use it in scope init driver logic, like if null then new driver instance is being creating. That command is optional however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `driver.close();` or `driver.quit();`.

Use `close()` for one browser to close and `quit()` is to close all browsers using webdriver. But why `close()` is not closed at runtime, but it is closed at debugging I don't know.

Comment: Your answer is weak (because you don't give much other information) and doesn't add much to the question and existing answers. You also asked a different question which really should be posted as a separate question (with a lot more information)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
    taskkill /f /fi "pid gt 0" /im iexplore.exe
```

I have this in my pre-build events in the Visual Studio Solution. This is can be run from the command line, just call it in your project and you should be all set.

I also have the following line to close the the IE driver in case of failure to execute `driver.Quit()` or `.Close()`

```
  taskkill /f /fi "pid gt 0" /im IEDriverServer.exe
```

Comment: Could you indicate how the questioner could run this within their code and with chrome?   I assume they want to incorporate it into their suite and not perform a one off action

Answer (score 0):

If you use headless mode you still see them not closing try this solution
1) Get the driver as singleton

```
@Singleton
class BrowserInstance {

ChromeDriver getDriver(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
    options.addArguments("--headless --disable-gpu")
    return new ChromeDriver(options)
   }
}
```

2) Use Close and quit in finally block

```
 finally {
        chromeDriver.close()
        chromeDriver.quit()
    }
```

Result: you will be using only one instance at time and if you see task manager you will not find chromedriver and chrome process hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution will be not a super smart one, but before each automated test case I put:

```
time.sleep(2)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

## Maximizes the window

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

And to close all windows of the test case I use:

```
def close():
    driver.close()
close()
```

And this works for me in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This will close only window, your selenium session still exists and you can execute your further processing using selenium driver.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Will this close one window and move to another? Or will it just switch between 2 windows keep both open?

Answer (score 0):

At least a part of the problem is likely because of the Python [local vs global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=local#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) behaviour of variables. Adding some comments to your code:

```python
def test_getResults(self):
    """ Get a test result """
    # The next line creates a local selenium web driver instance and connects it
    sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/') 
    sel.start()
    # do stuff
    # At this point sel goes out of scope but we have done nothing to stop it

def tearDown(self):
    """End of testing!"""
    # The next line creates a local selenium web driver instance and connects it
    sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/')
    sel.close() # Closes the local sel instance
    sel.stop() # Stops the local sel instance
```

So the `sel` instance that you create in `test_getResults` is not, by default, the one that you stop. Unless the `selenium` function that you do not show is:

1. Checking for an existing instance of the driver and if it exists calling get with the parameters then returning the handle for the driver
2. If the driver does not exist create and do get then return the handle

Since you give a self parameter to each method I presume that the methods are being created as class members **for the same class instance**. In that case something like:

```python
def test_getResults(self):
    """ Get a test result """
    # The next lines gets or creates a selenium web driver instance and connects it
    if not hasattirbute(self, 'sel) or self.sel is None:
        # No running instance available
        self.sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, "*chrome", 'http://blackpearl/')
        self.sel.start()
        sel = self.sel # Local variable to point to the class member
    else:
        sel = self.sel
        self.get('http://blackpearl/')
    
    # do stuff
    # At this point sel goes out of scope but but self.sel does not

def tearDown(self):
    """End of testing!"""
    if hasattirbute(self, 'sel) and self.sel is not None:
        self.sel.Quit()
        del self.sel # just in case self persists
    else:
        print("WARNING: tearDown called with nothing to do!")
```

Personally I would also `import atexit` and when creating `self.sel` [register](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) `self.tearDown` as an exit handler.